# Adjusting decimal precision, .net

Tags: .net, decimal, precision

These lines in C#

```
decimal a = 2m;
decimal b = 2.0m;
decimal c = 2.00000000m;
decimal d = 2.000000000000000000000000000m;

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(c);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Generates this output:

```
2
2.0
2.00000000
2.000000000000000000000000000
```

So I can see that creating a decimal variable from a literal allows me to control the precision.

- Can I adjust the precision of decimal variables without using literals?
- How can I create b from a?  How can I create b from c?

Comment: Valid question - the scaling factor can get changed subtly e.g. when decimal properties are serialized to JSON and back again from the UI, and then binary serialization e.g. BinaryFormatter will produce slightly different bytes e.g. if you try to make a hash of the object.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Preserving trailing zeroes like this was introduced in .NET 1.1 for more strict conformance with the ECMA CLI specification.

There is some info on this on MSDN, e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289527(VS.71).aspx).

You can adjust the precision as follows:

- Math.Round (or Ceiling, Floor etc) to decrease precision (b from c)
- Multiply by 1.000... (with the number of decimals you want) to increase precision - e.g. multiply by 1.0M to get b from a.

Comment: Also _divide_ by `1.000...` to decrease precision.

Answer (score 19):

You are just seeing different representations of the exact same data.  The precision of a `decimal` will be scaled to be as big as it needs to be (within reason).

From [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx):

> A decimal number is a floating-point
>   value that consists of a sign, a
>   numeric value where each digit in the
>   value ranges from 0 to 9, and ***a
>   scaling factor that indicates the
>   position of a floating decimal point
>   that separates the integral and
>   fractional parts of the numeric value.***
>
> The binary representation of a Decimal
>   value consists of a 1-bit sign, a
>   96-bit integer number, and a scaling
>   factor used to divide the 96-bit
>   integer and specify what portion of it
>   is a decimal fraction. The scaling
>   factor is implicitly the number 10,
>   raised to an exponent ranging from 0
>   to 28. Therefore, the binary
>   representation of a Decimal value is
>   of the form, ((-2<sup>96</sup> to 2<sup>96</sup>) / 10<sup>(0 to
>   28)</sup>), where -2<sup>96</sup>-1 is equal to
>   MinValue, and 2<sup>96</sup>-1 is equal to
>   MaxValue.
>
> ***The scaling factor also preserves any
>   trailing zeroes in a Decimal number.
>   Trailing zeroes do not affect the
>   value of a Decimal number in
>   arithmetic or comparison operations.
>   However, trailing zeroes can be
>   revealed by the ToString method if an
>   appropriate format string is applied.***

Comment: Good information about scaling factor... now how can I adjust it?

Comment: The scaling factor is not directly controllable, since it adjusts based on the size of the exponent. This is basically how floating point works (and where the term "floating" comes from). Since the number of bits in the significand is constant, the size of the number determines the scale of the significant bits.

Comment: It is automatically adjusted to fit the needs of the data it contains.  Is there a particular reason you need to scale it manually?

Comment: There is a reason - however, I feel that the reason does not add clarity to this question.  I will probably ask a separate question about the reason.

Comment: @AndrewHare I just need a quick confirmation - I believe the definition of precision (total digits in a number) and scale (total number of digits after the decimal point) is same in .net and SQL world for decimal data types. I think these concepts of precision and scale has to do with world of mathematics rather than .Net or SQL. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't that be -2<sup>96</sup>**+**1?

Comment: According to the documentation, decimal is 128 bits.  So one byte is for the sign, 96 bits are for the numeric value, and the exponent ranges from 0 to 28, requiring 5 bits.  What happens to the remaining 26 bits?  Are they just wasted space?  (Why the range 0-28, anyway, rather than making it 0-31, using the full range of the 5 bits?)

Comment: One *bit* is for the sign, rather.

Answer (score 9):

What about 
[Math.Round(decimal d, int decimals)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx)?

Comment: For .00 values you'll have to multiply with 1.00m first:  decimal.Round(value*1.00m, 2)

Answer (score 8):

I found that I could "tamper" with the scale by multiplying or dividing by a fancy 1.

```
decimal a = 2m;
decimal c = 2.00000000m;
decimal PreciseOne = 1.000000000000000000000000000000m;
  //add maximum trailing zeros to a
decimal x = a * PreciseOne;
  //remove all trailing zeros from c
decimal y = c / PreciseOne;
```

I can fabricate a sufficiently precise 1 to change scale factors by known sizes.

```
decimal scaleFactorBase = 1.0m;
decimal scaleFactor = 1m;
int scaleFactorSize = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < scaleFactorSize; i++)
{
  scaleFactor *= scaleFactorBase;
}

decimal z = a * scaleFactor;
```

Comment: Interesting, but at the same time puzzling.

What exactly is the difference between 2.0m and 2.00000000m ?

In non-computing environment, I would take this to mean that the latter number was guaranteed to that precision, whereas the former was only guaranteed to the first decimal point. However multiplication should mean that the result is only accurate to one decimal place.

Answer (score 6):

It's tempting to confuse `decimal` in SQL Server with `decimal` in .NET; they are quite different.

A SQL Server `decimal` is a fixed-point number whose precision and scale are fixed when the column or variable is defined.

A .NET `decimal` is a floating-point number like `float` and `double` (the difference being that `decimal` accurately preserves decimal digits whereas `float` and `double` accurately preserve binary digits). Attempting to control the precision of a .NET `decimal` is pointless, since all calculations will yield the same results regardless of the presence or absence of padding zeros.

Comment: interestingly, setting the facets on a decimal in EF creates a proper `SQL decimal` which promptly fails when a `c# decimal` is handed it... in my case I used Precision: 2, Scale: (none) and I can't assign `800` to it on account of the value being out of range

Answer (score 2):

This will remove all the trailing zeros from the decimal and then you can just use `ToString()`.

```
public static class DecimalExtensions
{
    public static Decimal Normalize(this Decimal value)
    {
        return value / 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, if you want an exact number of trailing zeros, say 5, first Normalize() and then multiply by 1.00000m.

Comment: No need for _that_ many zeroes, can do with 28 zeroes after the `1`. See comments to [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7983330/1336654).

Answer (score 1):

The question is -  do you really need the precision **stored** in the decimal, rather than just displaying the decimal to the required precision.
Most applications know internally how precise they want to be and display to that level of precision. For example, even if a user enters an invoice for 100 in an accounts package, it still prints out as 100.00 using something like val.ToString("n2").

> How can I create b from a? How can I create b from c?

c to b is possible.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(2.00000000m, 1))
```

produces 2.0

a to b is tricky as the concept of introducing precision is a little alien to mathematics.

I guess a horrible hack could be a round trip.

```
decimal b = Decimal.Parse(a.ToString("#.0"));
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

produces 2.0

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 7 there is a decimal.Scale property now. So we can write an extension method like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Fix decimal to show trailing zeros
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Input decimal</param>
    /// <param name="scale">Number of decimal places from 0 to 28</param>
    /// <returns>Fixed precision decimal</returns>
    public static decimal SetScale(this decimal input, int scale)
    {
        if (scale < 0 || scale > 28)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(scale));

        if (input.Scale == scale)
            return input;

        //normalize
        input /= 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;
        var scaleToadd = scale - input.Scale;
        for(int i = 0; i < scaleToadd; i++)
        {
            input *= 1.0M;
        }

        
        return input;
    }
```

And use it on a property to force precision and trailing zeros in the decimal.  [html textbox showing trailing zeros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bngJe.png):

```
    private decimal price;
    public decimal Price { get => price; set => price = value.SetScale(2); }
```