# How to format a decimal value WITHOUT rounding to store into nullable decimal Variable in c#

Tags: c#

I have tried to format(Truncate) a decimal value to 4 decimal places.  For example, I want to convert  decimal numbers like

```
31.818181818181818181818181818M  or 31.818181818181818181M or 31.81818M
```

to

```
31.8181
```

(NOT rounding to 31.8182)
And store it in to a nullable decimal variable. I have tried following [decimal formatting without rounding .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138217/decimal-formatting-without-rounding-net) and [Stop Rounding In C# At A Certain Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091421/stop-rounding-in-c-sharp-at-a-certain-number?lq=1) 
but no luck for nullable decimals.

Here is the code

```
private decimal? ReturnNullableDecimal(decimal? initValue)
{
        //e.g. initValue = 35M;
        initValue = 35M; //just to debug;

        decimal? outputValue = null;


        if (initValue != null)
            outputValue = initValue / (decimal)1.10;
        //now outputValue is 31.818181818181818181818181818M
        outputValue = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:0.0000}", outputValue)); // <- this should be 31.8181 but gives 31.8182

        return outputValue;
    }
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Bankers rounding is the default in a.net. I guess you need midpoint rounding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `decimal` can be implicitly converted to a `decimal?`, so the same code works as in any other example of truncating.  If your input is also a `decimal?`, you'll have to check for null there.

```
private decimal? ReturnNullableDecimal(decimal? initValue)
{
    if (initValue.HasValue)
        return Math.Truncate(10000 * initValue.Value) / 10000;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on accepted answer I created an Extension

```
namespace your.namespace.Extensions
{
    public static class NullableDecimalExtension
    {
        public static decimal? FormatWithNoRoundingDecimalPlaces(this decimal? initValue, int decimalPlaces)
        {
            if (decimalPlaces < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number. DecimalPlaces must be greater than Zero");
            }

            if (initValue.HasValue)
                return (decimal?)(Math.Truncate(Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces) * (double)initValue.Value) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces));
            else
               return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:
Add 
using your.namespace.Extensions; to the class

Then in the calling method it can directly call

e.g.

```
initValue = 35M;
decimal? outputValue = (initValue / (decimal)1.10).FormatWithNoRoundingDecimalPlaces(4);
//now the outputValue = 31.8181
```

If we need to get 2 decimal places just use .FormatWithNoRoundingDecimalPlaces(2);