# How to format a decimal without rounding it

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

Good day

How to i format a decimal without rounding it

```
TotalNumber.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or

```
TotalNumber.ToString("#,#")
```

These 2 strings are rounding 11822252.79 to 11,822,253

The results must be 11,822,252,79 or 11 822 252 79

Comment: refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857926/how-to-format-a-decimal-value-without-rounding-to-store-into-nullable-decimal-va][1]

Comment: Multiply by 100 first?  Are you mixing the thousandth separator and the decimal separator?  One should be a comma and the other a period.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a decimal value WITHOUT rounding to store into nullable decimal Variable in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857926/how-to-format-a-decimal-value-without-rounding-to-store-into-nullable-decimal-va)

Comment: the Culture you use has `,` as thousanths seperator. You are not rounding, your are telling it to display only thousands. Use `"#,###.00"` and Invariant culture to get `11,822,252.79`

Comment: `The results must be 11,822,252,79 or 11 822 252 79` Um, are you deliberately mixing up decimal and thousand separators there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Invariant Culture has `,` as thousanths seperator and `.` as decimals seperator.

You are not rounding, your format strings tells it to display only thousands, no decimals at all.

Use "#,###.00" and Invariant culture to get 11,822,252.79:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var n = 11822252.79m;

        Console.WriteLine( n.ToString("#,###.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11,822,252.79
```

See:

- [Doku #](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier)
- [Doku .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1)
- [Doku ,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-2)