# Site global rule for amount of decimals to print

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal

For display purposes, is it possible to set a site global rule for the amount of digits to display after the decimal separator ASP.NET MVC 4? In the event that it is, how does one achieve this?

The optimal method would be a culture related rule specified in web.config which affects all printed decimals.

Comment: With a for-loop?  You should elaborate on this. WebForm controls or MVC + jQuery makes a big difference.

Comment: How is that site global?

Comment: Do you mean displayed digits after the decimal separator or really the amount of decimal values allowed to be displayed?

Comment: I've clarified the question. I am referring to the displayed digits after the decimal separator. I wasn't aware of the fact that there was a difference.

Comment: You might be able to do it by tweaking a tostring method for the NumberFormatInfo part of the CultureInfo the site runs under (Globzliation).

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thanks Allan!

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? WebForms?

Comment: @haim770 I've already specified ASP.NET MVC 4 in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer, [Adjusting decimal precision, .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132765/adjusting-decimal-precision-net) the number of digits displayed depends on what you enter in the first place.

My guess however is that you are asking how to simply round the decimal? In which case you can just use Math.Round.

This quick answer as far as I am aware however is no, I am not aware of built-in global mechanism of limiting the number of digits displayed when outputting the number to the screen.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. The optimal method would be a culture related rule specified in web.config which affects all printed decimals.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `.ToString(format)` method to convert the number values to strings and you specify the "N" format, then you can use CultureInfo to set the number of decimal places:

```
var ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 1;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

decimal dm = 20.12345m;
double db = 20.12345;
Console.WriteLine(dm.ToString("N"));
Console.WriteLine(db.ToString("N"));
```

Both display with 1 decimal.