# Using 0M instead of 0 for decimal values?

Tags: c#

Is it necessary to add `M` for zero values for assignment and comparisons of `decimal` variable?

```
decimal val;
...
if (val == 0M)
{
}
```

or

```
if (val == 0)
{
}
```

I guess the constant will be converted at compile time and the result will be identical.

Comment: This could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269607/c-sharp-decimal-how-to-add-trailing-zeros?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes, `0` will be *implicitly* case to `decimal` at complie time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table; however, we must put `M` after `0.0` since "There are no implicit conversions between floating-point types and the decimal type"

Comment: The compiled IL is identical, so no it's not necessary in this situation.

Comment: Duplicate question, The answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/977562/4189817

Comment: IL for decimal `==` : `call bool [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Equality(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not necessary. Integer types are [casted implicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table) to `decimal`. You have to add the `M` suffix if the literal represents a *floating point number*. Floating point literals without a type suffix are `double` and those require an explicit cast to `decimal`.

```
decimal d = 1;     // works
decimal d2 = 1.0   // does not work
decimal d3 = 1.0M  // works
```

---

The literal `0` here is obviously  a special case of the integer literal.

Comment: bit late to the party here; not neccessary, i know - but what you think about readability? in my application i added to every long/decimal/double/float value the specific suffix `l`/`m`/`d`/`f` - so I know with just seeing the value, what exact type it is. good idea? or too much?