# .net decimal - remove scale, solution that is guaranteed to work

Tags: c#, decimal, language-lawyer

I want to convert a decimal a with scale > 0 to its equivalent decimal b with scale 0 (suppose that there is an equivalent decimal without losing precision). Success is defined by having `b.ToString()` return a string without any trailing zeroes or by extracting the scale via GetBits and confirming that it is 0.

Easy options I found:

```
        Decimal scale2 = new Decimal(100, 0, 0, false, 2);
        string scale2AsString = scale2.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        // toString includes trailing zeroes
        Assert.IsTrue(scale2AsString.Equals("1.00"));

        // can use format specifier to specify format
        string scale2Formatted = scale2.ToString("G0");
        Assert.IsTrue(scale2Formatted.Equals("1"));

        // but what if we want to pass the decimal to third party code that does not use format specifiers?

        // option 1, use Decimal.Truncate or Math.Truncate (Math.Truncate calls Decimal.Truncate, I believe)
        Decimal truncated = Decimal.Truncate(scale2);
        string truncatedAsString = truncated.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.IsTrue(truncatedAsString.Equals("1"));

        // option 2, division trick
        Decimal divided = scale2 / 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;
        string dividedAsString = divided.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.IsTrue(dividedAsString.Equals("1"));

        // option 3, if we expect the decimal to fit in int64, convert to int64 and back
        Int64 asInt64 = Decimal.ToInt64(scale2);
        Decimal backToDecimal = new Decimal(asInt64);
        string backToDecimalString = backToDecimal.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.IsTrue(backToDecimalString.Equals("1"));

        // option 4, convert to BigInteger then back using BigInteger's explicit conversion to decimal
        BigInteger convertedToBigInteger = new BigInteger(scale2);
        Decimal bigIntegerBackToDecimal = (Decimal)convertedToBigInteger;
        string bigIntegerBackToDecimalString = bigIntegerBackToDecimal.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.IsTrue(bigIntegerBackToDecimalString.Equals("1"));
```

So plenty of options, and certainly there are more. But which of these options are actually guaranteed to work?

Option 1: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.truncate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not mention that the scale is changed when calling `Truncate`, so using this method seems to be relying on an implementation detail. Internally, Truncate calls [FCallTruncate](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,0f95f1407d35e2da,references), for which I did not find any documentation.

Option 2 [may be mandated by the CLI spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133880/37117), but I did not find which exact specification that would be, I did not find it in the ECMA specification.

Option 3 (ToInt64 also uses [FCallTruncate](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,0f95f1407d35e2da,references) internally) will work judging by the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,a038dc0770de0a93) (the constructor taking an ulong sets flags and this scale to 0) but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/954wac29%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) again makes no mention of scale.

Option 4, [BigInteger calls Decimal.Truncate](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,9a0d4d6e3b7f0138), with the comment:

```
        // First truncate to get scale to 0 and extract bits
        int[] bits = Decimal.GetBits(Decimal.Truncate(value));
```

So clearly Microsoft internally also thinks that Decimal.Truncate will set the scale to 0.

But I am looking for a method that is guaranteed to work without relying on implementation details and works for all the decimal where this can technically work (cannot rescale a Decimal.MaxValue for example). None of the options above seems to fit the bill for this requirement.

Comment: How do you define "best"?  Fastest?  Easiest to understand?  Least memory usage?  Have you done any benchmarking on the options you seem to already understand fairly well?

Comment: Are you confusing `scale` with `precision`?  Scale is the number of digits, precision is the number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @ps2goat: I construct a decimal either with new Decimal(100, 0, 0, false, 2); or with new Decimal(1, 0, 0, false, 0); The are the same numeric value, but differ in scale (at least this is the nomenclature that the documentation for the constructor uses). Therefore I think I indeed mean scale not precision, but sure, I may be confused.

Comment: @DStanley: Most importantly, I want a method that is documented to work, not rely on implementation details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much answered your question yourself. Personally, I would not obsess so much about which method to use. If you method works now - even if it is undocumented - then it will most likely work in the future. And if a future update to .NET breaks your method then hopefully you have a test that will highlight this when you upgrade your application framework.

Going through your options:

1) `Decimal.Truncate` sets the scale to 0 but if it is undocumented then you may decide to not rely on this fact.

2) Dividing by `1.0000 ...` may give you the desired result but it is not obvious what is going and if it is not documented then this is probably the worst option.

3 and 4) These options should work for you. You convert the decimal to an integer and then back to a decimal. Obviously, the decimal created from an integer has scale 0. Any other value would be wrong even though it is not explicitly documented. Option 4) is able to handle even `Decimal.MaxValue` and `Decimal.MinValue`.