# Generating a decimal with trailing zeros

Tags: c#

I need to round a decimal to a specific number of significant figures. I have a library that can be simplified as shown.

```
decimal a = Math.Round(20.051M * 100M) / 100M; // 20.05
decimal b = Math.Round(20.001M * 100M) / 100M; // 20;
```

Clearly I lost the trailing zeros when performing the `Round`, I can get them back by adding `.00M` Is there a way to do this dynamically, if I were rounding to five significant figures I would want to use `.000M`, likewise if my decimal was < 10 `.000M` would be appropriate.

```
b = b + .00M; // 20.00
```

For reference here is the actual rounding method.

**DecimalExtensions.cs**

```
private static readonly decimal[] Pows = Enumerable.Range(-28, 57).Select(p => (decimal)Math.Pow(10, p)).ToArray();

/// <remarks>https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146056/3194005</remarks>
public static decimal RoundToSignificantFigures(this decimal value, int significantFigures)
{
    if (value == 0)
        return 0;

    int d = Log10Ceiling(Math.Abs(value));
    int power = significantFigures - d;

    decimal magnitude = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, power);

    return Math.Round(value * magnitude) / magnitude;
}

private static int Log10Ceiling(decimal value)
{
    int log10 = Array.BinarySearch(Pows, value);

    return (log10 >= 0 ? log10 : ~log10) - 28;
}
```

Comment: if it is just for display purposes String.Format

Comment: It isn't for display, it's needed to enforce significant figure rules. For example downstream `a` and `b` could get averaged. The result can only be as precise as the least precise input. In this case that's a difference between 20 and 20.02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a value with the required number of zeros after the decimal point by computing the value of mag<sup>-1</sup>, and subtracting it from itself:

```
var res = Math.Round(value * magnitude) / magnitude;
var invMag = 1/magnitude;
return res + invMag - invMag;
```

In your example mag=10<sup>2</sup>, so invMag=10<sup>-2</sup>, or 0.01. When you subtract `0.01M - 0.01M` you end up with `0.00M`, which you can add to result to force it to have the desired number of trailing zeros without changing the value.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/qYVBTp)

Comment: This appears to be working, as soon as I've consumed what it's doing I'll accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, is too long for a comment, and too specific for a new question, so...

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47122370/13087) here, and discovered an anomaly, whereby the [dotnetfiddle compiler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D53eXd) returns 20 for your example:

```
decimal b = Math.Round(20.001M * 100M) / 100M; 
b = b + .00M;
```

Whereas it (correctly) returns 20.00 for:

```
decimal b = Math.Round(20.001M * 100M) / 100M; 
b = Decimal.Add(b, .00M);
```

Both return 20.00 with the Visual Studio compilers I have tried (VS2013, VS2015).

I don't know if this is a compiler bug, but in the absence of an explanation I'd prefer the second version.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in C# 5.0 compiler. It optimize `b + .00M` as `b`.

Answer (score -1):

The value of 20M is the same as 20.00M, if it's formatting for the user just do

```
20M.ToString("0.00");
```

Checkout NumberFormatInfo - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `20M` and `20.00M` are equal, but not the same: `decimal.GetBits(20M)` return `int[4] { 20, 0, 0, 0 }`, while `decimal.GetBits(20.00M)` return `int[4] { 2000, 0, 0, 131072 }`.

Comment: What if you want to preserve decimals?  E.g. if you want to negate a numerical string value, preserving decimals.  An easy way to do this is `(-Decimal.Parse(stringValue)).ToString()`  which gives the right result without the caller needing to know how many decimals are in the input.